# Do the balls keep moving forever?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, friction, inertial-frames, collision

In a hypothetical world where there is no friction, and all collisions are elastic would an object in lateral motion be perpetually moving and never come to a stop?

Assumptions:

- Perfect vacuum: zero air friction
- Elastic collisions: no loss of momentum
- Zero friction with the ground

Comment: Conservation laws tell yes. If there is no momentum lost, it will be there forever.

Comment: Elastic means no loss of _kinetic_ energy.

Comment: No: gravitational radiation will take energy out of the system.

Comment: How would you define moving? Relative to what. A single moving ball in a void would be indistinguishable from a stationary one.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  For example, if a moving ball were to hit another ball of the same mass at rest, the moving ball could stop dead, having transferred all it's momentum to the other ball.

Comment: but this assumes another ball was already at rest.